# .NET Core Roslyn cannot find System.Decimal in assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn

I'm using **Roslyn** to compile my class in runtime to `assembly` output. I've added my needed assemblies into metadata references as below:

```
string p = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
_ref = new MetadataReference[] {
     MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(p, "System.Collections.dll")),
     MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(p, "System.Runtime.dll")),
     MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(Path.Combine(p, "System.Private.CoreLib.dll")),
     MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),          
     MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(Schema).Assembly.Location)
};
```

And my CSharp syntax tree:

```
using System;

namespace _
{
    public sealed class Model : Record
    {
        public string name;
        public decimal amount;
        public bool granted;
        public DateTime birthdate;
    }
}
```

And when I use my `dll` file in **another project**, I got an error when I create an instance of `Model`, the error is located on my `decimal` property which is `amount`. Omnisharp shows me:

```
The type 'Decimal' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

As far as I known, the `System.Private.CoreLib.dll` has been existed in `typeof(object).Assembly.Location`, so it doesn't make any sense if still giving me the error.

What's wrong here??

Comment: This is not fun code to write correctly.  The core problem is that typeof(object).Assembly doesn't do what you hope it does.  The distinction between reference assemblies and runtime assemblies is a very big deal in .NETCore.  A possible way to get this right is to do this in a VS .netcore project and right-click a type name, select Go To Definition.  You'll see the reference assembly name.  Exactly where they need to come from is pretty murky however, you may have to include them with your project.  Note how a lot of nuget packages do that.

Comment: @hans-passant I've tried in VS, I don't know how to get the right path of my needed assemblies to make Roslyn compile my syntax tree successfully.

Comment: You have got answer here https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/2082